# TL-WN823N not working with Pi Zero

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-zero

I bought myself TP-WN823N WiFi dongle for my Pi Zero. I can't connect with WiFi. I looked with *lsusb* and found that it isn't connected as USB device.

I have USB hub (non-powered) where I have keyboard and mouse and that WiFi dongle. I have also tried to connect that WiFi tongle alone but still no activity light.

Is it possible that Pi Zero doesn't support that WiFi dongle?

I am using Raspbian 4.4.11+ and powering with 1A. I think the power isn't limit cause I use 0.5A with keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 1):

The dongle is supported. You can't find the dongle via `lsusb`, this means the dongle isn't not connected. You have a non-powered usb hub with a keyboard and mouse, this seems like the problem. Even if the dongle is getting .5A, that may not be enough. Note, this can also be a problem of the hub, the hub can also be drawing more power than expected. This is a simple thing to verify, just unplug the hub and connect the wifi adapter directly to the board and see if it's detected (you can use a bash loop to keep running `lsusb`).

Comment: Too bad that that I don't have it any more. I would have tried it. I bought Endimax N150 (http://us.edimax.com/edimax/merchandise/merchandise_detail/data/edimax/us/wireless_adapters_n150/ew-7811un/) and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

First connect raspberry pi zero to internet via usb cable to your phone in tethering mode.
Update and upgrade distro

Comment: Updated and upgraded. It now recognizes that device but doesn't show name. I also tried steps that are described here https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=148389&p=1028428 but still no luck...